# Wildly discontinuous linear functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $H\subseteq X$ be a dense hyperplane, and $f$ be a **continuous** linear functional defined on $H$.  Then $f$ is uniformly continuous and hence it admits a unique continuous extension to $X$.

However, let us instead choose a **discontinuous** linear functional $g$ extending $f$ to the whole of $X$.

One cannot say that $g$ is too bad since, after all, its restriction to a big subspace, namely $H$, is continuous.

> Does every Banach space admit a linear functional which is either zero or
> discontinuous when restricted to every infinite dimensional subspace?

The kernel of such a functional will then have a dense intersection with every infinite dimensional subspace.

Comment: For any linear functional $f$ on an infinite-dimensional Banach space, the kernel of $f$ is a subspace with codimension 1, hence also infinite dimensional, and the restriction of $f$ to its kernel is 0 which is certainly continuous...  did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @Nate, thanks! That does highlight a big flaw in my thinking.  Would it still be 
a trivial question if we restrict to infinite dimensional subspaces not contained in the kernel?

Comment: moreover, there aren't that many ways of extending f from H to X. All extensions are proportional.

Comment: @Pietro, that is true, but these are precisely the functionals I would not consider wildly discontinuous.

Comment: @Pietro, there is only one continuous extension, but infinitely many linear ones, so surely one will be discontinuous (I take back my "that is true" of 2 comments ago).

Comment: @Pietro, do you agree that a uniformly continuous function defined on a dense subset admits a **unique** continuous extension to the whole space?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the question!

Comment: @Nate, I hope the question now makes some sense after the last edit.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No non zero linear functional has the property you ask for. Suppose $F$ is a non zero linear functional. Choose $x$ s.t. $F(x)=1$. Let $G$ be a continuous linear functional s.t. $G(x)=1$. Let $Y$ be the intersection of the kernels of $F$ and $G$, so that $Y$ has codimension $2$. Then $F$ is continuous on the linear span of $Y$ and $x$ since $F$ agrees with $G$ on this codimension one subspace.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  I guess this also shows that there is no subspace $H$ whose intersection with any closed hyperplane is dense.  If there was one, you could put $H$ inside some hyperplane, see it as the kernel of a functional $F$  and then use the same argument.