# Is it possible to classify non-closed subspaces of Hilbert's space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be Hilbert's space.

Motivated by my previous question about [wildly discontinuous linear functionals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373012/wildly-discontinuous-linear-functionals), which may  be interpreted as an attempt to classify dense hyperplanes in $H$, let me now go straight to the point:

**Questions**.

1. Are there any significant differences among dense hyperplanes in $H$?
2. If $L$ and $M$ are two dense hyperplanes in $H$,  is there a unitary operator mapping $L$ to $M$?
3. Assuming the answer to (2) is negative,  how many orbits are there for the
   natural action of the unitary group $\mathscr U(H)$ on the set of dense hyperplanes?

---

Speaking about general (not necessarily closed or dense) subspaces of $H$,  there are a few things one may say in that
respect.

For example,  not all such spaces may be described as the range of a bounded operator and, in particular, no
dense hyperplane qualifies.  This is because, if the  range  of such an operator  has finite co-dimension,  it must be
closed (this follows easily from the Closed Graph Theorem).

The range of a compact operator does not contain any infinite dimensional closed subspace, so that is another property one could use
to classify subspaces.

**More Questions**.

4. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition, expressed in topological/analytical terms, characterizing the range of
   a bounded (resp. compact) operator among all subspaces of $H$?
5. How many unitary equivalence classes of non-closed subspaces of $H$ are there?   How many of these may be described in
   topological/analytical terms?

Comment: As to 2 and 3, the linear dual of $H$ has more elements than the unitary group of $H$.

Comment: Thanks for a very interesting comment!  So there are indeed lots of different unitarily equivalence classes of dense hyperplanes.  I'd be very curious to see examples of two such classed being distinguished by analytic properties!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have a simple answer to Question 4, in the compact case: An infinite dimensional  subspace $E\subseteq H$ is the range of a compact operator
iff there exists an orthogonal (as opposed to orthonormal)  set $\{e_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}\subseteq E$, such that
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty }\Vert e_n\Vert  = \infty ,
  $$
and
$$
  E=\Big\{\xi \in \overline{\text{span}\{e_n\}}: \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big|\langle \xi , e_n\rangle \Big|^2<\infty  \Big\}.
  $$
This follows easily from the Spectral Theorem for compact operators, and the fact that the range of a compact operator
$T$ coincides with  the range of $|T|$.